# FastAPI app results in 404 error response when it is started using uvicorn.run

Tags: python-3.x, http-status-code-404, fastapi, uvicorn

New to FastAPI and uvicorn, but I'm wondering why when I run my "hello world" service by starting it using uvicorn from the command line, it works fine, but when using the "uvicorn.run" method from inside my service, the service starts, but when I send a GET I always get a `404` with a response body of `{"detail": "Not Found"}`?

Here is my code:

```
import uvicorn
from fastapi import FastAPI

app = FastAPI()
uvicorn.run(app, host="127.0.0.1", port=5049)


@app.get("/")
async def root():
    return {"message": "Hello World"}
```

That always returns with a 404 as follows:

```
# curl http://127.0.0.1:5049/
{"detail":"Not Found"}
```

The output from my service shows:

```
INFO:     Started server process [28612]
INFO:     Waiting for application startup.
INFO:     Application startup complete.
INFO:     Uvicorn running on http://127.0.0.1:5049 (Press CTRL+C to quit)
INFO:     127.0.0.1:55446 - "GET / HTTP/1.1" 404 Not Found
```

If I comment out the "uvicorn.run" line and then start the service from the command line with (running on Windows 10):

```
uvicorn.exe test:app --host=127.0.0.1 --port=5049
```

I get the correct response:

```
# curl http://127.0.0.1:5049/
{"message":"Hello World"}
```

Comment: With regard to `404 Not Found` error responses, future readers might find the following answers helpful: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74498663/17865804), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73113792/17865804), as well as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76528465/17865804) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76057623/17865804)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Because, the statement ***`uvicorn.run(app, host="127.0.0.1", port=5049)`*** is executed before the **`root(...)`** function and the execution is never reaching to the `root(...)` function.

But, when you run the app using the command line, the app is loaded in a ***lazy*** fashion, and hence the `root(...)` function is getting executed.

Something like this would surely resolve the issue:

```
import uvicorn
from fastapi import FastAPI

app = FastAPI()


@app.get("/")
async def root():
    return {"message": "Hello World"}


 # at last, the bottom of the file/module
if __name__ == "__main__":
    uvicorn.run(app, host="127.0.0.1", port=5049)
```

Answer (score -2):

I just replaced the previous port with another port. and this works. to change the port like this:

`uvicorn ..... --port=some_port`

previous port :

`uvicorn .....` *default port is **8000***

[previous port image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xBxbE.png)

port after replacement :

`uvicorn ..... --port=9090`

[port after replacemen image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dnKuX.png)

Comment: The answer is not answering the question, the problem wasn't that the port is different is  that the code is not running unless you comment out a line of code.